# How can we make a software which can be installed?

Tags: python, windows

I have no experience in making a program into an software. I want to mimic a software out there because the software is simple and yet not free. I want to use python as the language chosen. So what is the process/steps to make an software using python? The software should be okay in Windows.

I only have experience in making a standalone program. I think we need to make the program install to the computer. But I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I got what you are asking for either, but among the most typical ways to create installations or executables there are:

- [Distutils](http://docs.python.org/distutils/index.html) (part of the standard library)
- [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) (cross-platform)
- [Py2Exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) (windows only)

HTH!

Comment: @gunbuster - Have you actually visited the sites I already linked?!?! :( The first link is to a page whose first line says: *"This document describes how to use the Distutils"*, the second and third have a prominent link in the menu called *"Help/Guide"* and *"Help content"* that - surprise, surprise! - provide help and instructions on how to use the utilities! If you get stuck somewhere along the way, post a new question with your code, and I am sure somebody will jump-in to help...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite certain I understand what you're asking, but I'm guessing you want a way to create an installable and uninstallable windows program from a python program. If so, a combination of [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) and [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) is one way to go.

**Edit:** You're probably better off using one of mac's suggestions. The above way is likely unnecessarily complicated.